# Touchpad - Fusuma problem when changing the language

Tags: touchpad, language-support, gestures

Ubuntu 20.04

Fusuma is not working when I change the language to Arabic, but it's working perfectly fine in English language.

It suddenly lags out the whole PC "if used a shortcut multiple times".

Installation

```
sudo gpasswd -a $USER input
newgrp input
sudo apt-get install libinput-tools
sudo apt-get install ruby
sudo gem install fusuma
fusuma
```

and I added it as a startup command.

Comment: This certainly sounds like a bug. You might get a solution if you [open a bug report](https://github.com/iberianpig/fusuma/issues) with the project developer 

Answer (score 1):

i used fusuma-sendkey instead of xdotool as suggested by the developer.
https://github.com/iberianpig/fusuma#alternatives-to-xdotool